# Converting stereo_msgs/DisparityImage to sensor_msgs/Image

Tags: ros, kinect, mjpeg-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a simple way to display a `stereo_msgs/DisparityImage` topic using [mjpeg_server](http://wiki.ros.org/mjpeg_server/), which needs images in the `sensor_msgs/Image` format. I'm getting the disparity image from a Kinect thorough the openNI package.

Is there a simple way to convert the disparity image to a flat image, or will I have to write up a custom process to handle the conversion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146096/converting-stereo_msgs/disparityimage-to-sensor_msgs/image/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vdonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/14946/vdonkey/) on 2014-05-05**:
Hi, have you work it out? I have the same question

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-05-29**:
Not yet! I've been distracted by other things to work on, but I'll get back to that soon and post once I have a solution!

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-03-16**:
@nckswt any solution yet?

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-03-16**:
I ended up finding a workaround to my problem instead, without having to display the `DisparityImage`. Sorry, no solution found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The stereo_msgs/Disparity Image topic contains a sensor_msgs/Image which you can easily pull out and convert to a 8 bit sensor_msgs/Image using some simple OpenCV operations.

You could imagine something like this:

```
void disparityCallback(const stereo_msgs::DisparityImagePtr disparity)
{
    
    cv::Mat_<float> disparityMat(disparity->image.height,
                                               disparity->image.width,
                                               reinterpret_cast<float*>(&(disparity->image.data[0])));

    cv::Mat_<uint8_t> eightBitDisparityMat = disparityMat * (255/disparity->max_disparity);

    sensor_msgs::Image eightBitDisparity;

    uint32_t imageSize = disparity->image.height * disparity->image.width;

    eightBitDisparity.data.resize(imageSize);
    memcpy(&eightBitDisparity.data[0], &(eightBitDisparityMat.at<uint8_t>(0,0)), imageSize);
    
    // Populate the rest of the sensor_msgs::Image fields
}
```

---

Originally posted by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) with karma: 80 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0